# Group array elements and calculate price

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Please advice how to group the same elements of array, calculate cost (and total) and output string like:

BBQ - Small (26cm) x 2 - 26.98$

Bolognese - Small (26cm) x 3 - 36$

Coca-cola 0.5 - 1$

....

Total: 120.96$

---

Array in JSON format:

```
[{"name":"BBQ - Small (26cm)","params":"","price":"12.99"},
{"name":"Coca-cola 0.5","params":"","price":"1"},
{"name":"BBQ - Small (26cm)","params":"","price":"12.99"},
{"name":"BBQ - Mid (31cm)","params":"","price":"14.99"},
{"name":"BBQ - Small (26cm)","params":"","price":"12.99"},
{"name":"Bolognese - Small (26cm)","params":"","price":"12"},
{"name":"Coca-cola 0.5","params":"","price":"1"},
{"name":"BBQ - Small (26cm)","params":"","price":"12.99"}]
```

Comment: There is more than 2x bbq small 26 cm. Or an I missing something?

Comment: I think you could have put a bit more effort into this yourself. What have you tried? Show us! What problems do you have with your code?

Comment: also 2* 12.99 = 25.98 and not 26.98 ?

Comment: And my code sums it uo to 80.95 not 120.96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the array and build an associative result array.
Add a new item if the item does not exist previously in the array.

Then add 1 to the count and add the price to the subtotal of that item.

```
$new['total'] =0;

foreach($arr as $sub){
    if(!isset($new[$sub['name']]['count'])){
        $new[$sub['name']]['count'] = 0;
        $new[$sub['name']]['total'] = 0;
    }
    $new[$sub['name']]['count']++;
    $new[$sub['name']]['total'] += $sub['price'];
    $new['total'] += $sub['price'];
}
var_export($new);
```

Returns:

```
array (
  'total' => 80.95,
  'BBQ - Small (26cm)' => 
  array (
    'count' => 4,
    'total' => 51.96,
  ),
  'Coca-cola 0.5' => 
  array (
    'count' => 2,
    'total' => 2,
  ),
  'BBQ - Mid (31cm)' => 
  array (
    'count' => 1,
    'total' => 14.99,
  ),
  'Bolognese - Small (26cm)' => 
  array (
    'count' => 1,
    'total' => 12,
  ),
```

https://3v4l.org/JbTf6